# how to find the next closest date in with my given date mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have some examples dates given below.How to find the next closest date in php or in mysql ?

I have some date like `12-04-2015` so now i need to get the closest date after the given date.So in my case my closest date is `15-04-2015`.How can i find using PHP and mysql ?? Any one help me

**PHP**

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");// current date
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
```

**Mysql**

```
SELECT Birthdate FROM hedging ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(Birthdate , `2015-04-12`)) LIMIT 1
```

How can i execute the above query in mysql ?

```
BirthDate
25-03-2015
10-04-2015
10-04-2015
11-04-2015
15-04-2015
30-04-2015
```

Answer (score 1):

You've not given us much information about what you've tried.

In PHP, store the dates in an array, you can then simply sort it and choose the next value.

In SQL so long as they are stored as dates, then `WHERE date > $date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1` will give you the next date.